# Slow Azure Table query with range filter on the RowKey

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I recently upgraded from Azure SDK 1 to SDK 2 and I converted the following code:

```
public IEnumerable<AnonymousSessionEntity> GetAnonymousSessions(Guid visitorId, Guid customerId, int connectionId, MergeOption mergeOption = MergeOption.AppendOnly)
{
    try
    {
        var partitionKey = AzureUtil.CombineToKey(customerId, connectionId);

        _tableStorageServiceContext.MergeOption = mergeOption;
        _tableStorageServiceContext.ResolveType = (unused) => typeof(AnonymousSessionEntity);

        var query = from s in _tableStorageServiceContext.CreateQuery<AnonymousSessionEntity>(TableStorageServiceContext.AnonymousSessionEntityName)
                         .Where(s => s.PartitionKey == partitionKey && s.RowKey.CompareTo(AzureUtil.GetRowKeyTimeLimit(90)) <= 0 && s.VisitorId == visitorId)
                    select s;

        CloudTableQuery<AnonymousSessionEntity> cloudTableQuery = query.AsTableServiceQuery<AnonymousSessionEntity>();
        IEnumerable<AnonymousSessionEntity> anonymousSessions = cloudTableQuery.Execute();

        return anonymousSessions;
    }
    catch (DataServiceQueryException e)
    {
        if (e.Response.StatusCode == (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound) return null;
        else throw;
    }
}
```

into the following:

```
public IEnumerable<AnonymousSessionEntity> GetAnonymousSessions(Guid visitorId, Guid customerId, int connectionId)
{
    var partitionKey = AzureUtil.CombineToKey(customerId, connectionId);
    var pkFilter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, partitionKey);
    var rkFilter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.LessThan, AzureUtil.GetRowKeyTimeLimit(90));
    var visitorIdFilter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForGuid("VisitorId", QueryComparisons.Equal, visitorId);
    var combinedFilter = string.Format("({0}) {1} ({2}) {3} ({4})", pkFilter, TableOperators.And, rkFilter, TableOperators.And, visitorIdFilter);

    var table = GetCloudTable(TableStorageDataSource.AnonymousSessionEntityName);
    var rangeQuery = new TableQuery<AnonymousSessionEntity>().Where(combinedFilter);

    var result = table.ExecuteQuery<AnonymousSessionEntity>(rangeQuery);
    return result;
}
```

As you can see, I have a filter on the partitionKey and also on the RowKey and on a custom field (called "VisitorId"). This query worked great with SDK 1 but the new version is very slow. In fact, it's so slow that it leads me to believe that Azure does a full table scan (I stopped counting after more than a minute). I have a few million rows in this table so I absolutely have to avoid table scans.

For testing purposes, I removed the filter on the "VisitorId" field in the v2 query and it performs very fast: probably 2-3 seconds.

Is there a way to build a fast query with the following criteria:

1. Exact Match on the PartitionKey
2. Range filter on the RowKey
3. Exact match on a custom field

Comment: I can provide some ideas but their working may depend on other query needs you may have.
Ideally you can have another table with VisitorId being pre-pended to your current RowKey.
Another idea it to suffix the VisitorId to your current PrimaryKey, to use for this query and use a PartitionKey range to support your other primary query.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will make a difference but there is a TableQuery.CombineFilters(string, string, string) method you can try using instead of string.Format. Like I said I'm not sure this will make a difference but it might be worth a try. If this doesn't work you might have to get crafty with your rowkey.

var combinedFilter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(pkFilter, TableOperators.And, TableQuery.CombineFilters(rkFilter, TableOperators.And, visitorIdFilter));